# Heroku git push master hangs

Tags: php, heroku, push

git push heroku master hangs for a long time .I did not get any response. I follwed all the steps to set the heroku account.

Can anyone share how to debug this?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: I did not get any error message just it hangs for a long time.But i tried the following command                                                         GIT_SSH=./sshv.sh git push heroku master                                                  OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/srmarimuthu/.ssh/c
debug1: identity file /c/Users/srmarimuthu/.ssh/identity type
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /c/Users/srmarimuthu/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'